# SEO Redirecting if Javascript Disabled

Tags: javascript, seo, meta-tags

My website relies heavily on Javascipt. Therefore, if the user has Javascript disabled I redirect them to another page using the meta tag shown below. To my knowledge web crawlers do not use Javascript (I think). Will this have any impact on my SEO? Will popular crawlers be able to crawl my website, or only the page I redirect them to?

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/noscript">
</noscript>
```

Comment: If the crawler has javascript disable then yes it will be redirected. After I'm not sure what are the popular crawler settings are but I believe nowadays a lot of them might have it on. However if you are worry about SEO then you should degrade gracefully when JS is disable instead of reqirecting them. I assume the page you redirect them too doesn't have the same information available if you worry about SEO? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/23535/how-important-is-graceful-degradation-of-javascript

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO / asking for behavior of search engine services. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0):

Google will treat a meta refresh with a 0 second delay as a 301 redirect. When considering search engine spiders, I always assume they have JS and cookies disabled, even though they can parse JS.

See http://sebastians-pamphlets.com/google-and-yahoo-treat-undelayed-meta-refresh-as-301-redirect/ for an old, but detailed explanation, which from my own experience, is still accurate.